# Set custom Annotation inside method?

Tags: java, unit-testing, annotations

I develop simple unit test library, just for fun and experience. As long as I write unit tests, I follow given-when-then or arrange-act-assert pattern. So I thought, that instead of write this pattern names as single line comments in test method body:

```
@TestClass(enabled = false)
public class DemonstrationTest {

    @UnitTest
    public void StringBuilderSuccess() throws AssertFailureException{
        //Given
        String firstTitle = "CosmicWhale";
        String secondTitle = "AmbientTurtle";
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String expected = firstTitle + " " + secondTitle;

        //When
        String actual = stringBuilder.append(firstTitle).append(" ").append(secondTitle).toString();

        //Then
        btester.framework.Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }
}
```

I can create annotations, to follow this pattern. This is much more elegant:

```
@UnitTest
    public void StringBuilderSuccess() throws AssertFailureException{
        @Given
        String firstTitle = "CosmicWhale";
        String secondTitle = "AmbientTurtle";
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String expected = firstTitle + " " + secondTitle;

        @When
        String actual = stringBuilder.append(firstTitle).append(" ").append(secondTitle).toString();

        @Then
        String localVariable;
        btester.framework.Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }
```

My problem is, that each of these annotations, must be above some local variable. This is not a problem with @Given and @When annotations, but it is a big problem with the last, @Then annotation. I've created redundand local variable under @Then annotation, to bypass the problem.

Question: Is there any chance to place annotation above Assert in the code?

Each annotation body looks lika this:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
@Target(ElementType.LOCAL_VARIABLE)
public @interface When {

}
```

I'm using Java 8.
I will be grateful for any help.

Ps. If you want to check or contribute my project, you can found it [here](https://github.com/SpaceDolphin/bTester).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java 8 does not permit writing annotations on statements.
It was considered, but not included in Java 8.

Here is some background.

Java 5+ permits writing annotations on declarations.
Java 8+ permits writing annotations on types.

The Java 8 feature for writing annotations on types was known by its code name ["JSR 308"](http://types.cs.washington.edu/jsr308/).  Java 8 made some other extensions to Java annotations, such as permitting duplicate annotations, and representing declaration annotations on local variables in the classfile.  JSR 308 also considered other [extensions to annotations](http://types.cs.washington.edu/jsr308/specification/java-annotation-extensions.html), including [annotations on statements](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://bitbucket.org/typetools/jsr308-langtools/raw/tip/doc/AnnotationsOnStatements.html).  Although annotations on statements have a number of [use cases](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://bitbucket.org/typetools/jsr308-langtools/raw/tip/doc/AnnotationsOnStatements.html#Use_Cases), in the end JSR 308, and therefore Java 8, [did not include](http://types.cs.washington.edu/jsr308/current/jsr308-faq.html#statement_annotations) the annotations-on-statements feature.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know : annotation can be applied to methods only when they are being declared, not when being called.

I dont see any clear use of annotations for above code. but, if you really want to just have annotations

wrap the assertion statement with a method which returns non void data type. (probably boolean ?)

in above implementation an annotation will be applied to return value of method. ( you may choose to store it with a variable name)

Comment: Yeah, I 've thought about it, but even if Assert method returns boolean, I have to catch it in some local variable. I guess nobody  (even me) will want to create local variable on Assert method only for @Then purpose. But thank you for your answer. I will think about another solution of this problem.